# How to capture the selected rows in jquery grid when submitting as part of the form in Struts2

Tags: jquery, struts2

I am using jquery grid and Struts2. I have displayed the jquery grid successfully. Now i want to select rows from jquery grid plus other data outside grid and submit that in my struts action for processing. I have a problem with retrieving the data from jquery grid. can anyone help on how to access the rows that i have selected from jquery grid in my action?

here is my jquery grid:

```
<s:form action="runTest" method="post">
                <sjg:grid
                    id="gridTable"
                    formIds="mcp"
                    caption="Test Scripts"
                    dataType="json"
                    href="%{searchurl}"
                    pager="true"
                    gridModel="gridTDP"
                    rowList="10,15,20,30"
                    rowNum="30"
                    multiselect="true"
                    viewrecords="true"
                    reloadTopics="reloadItems"
                    loadonce="false"
                    viewsortcols="[true, 'horizontal', true]"
                    resizable="true"
                >

                    <sjg:gridColumn name="idTestData"
                        index="idTestData"
                        key="true"
                        title="idTestData"
                        formatter="integer"
                        hidden="true"
                    />

                    <sjg:gridColumn name="testName"
                        index="testName"
                        title="Test Name"
                        width="50"
                        sortable="true"
                        search="true"
                        searchoptions="{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}"
                    />
                    <sjg:gridColumn
                        name="projectName"
                        index="projectName"
                        title="Project Name"
                        width="300"
                        sortable="true"
                        edittype="text"
                    />

                </sjg:grid>

                <sj:submit value="Execute Test Scripts"/>
            </s:form>
```

Here is the runTest.action which is successfully called on but not getting the jquery grid rows:

```
public String runTest() throws Exception{

        Iterator<Test> gridIterator = gridTDP.iterator();

        System.out.println(" running test--");
        while(gridIterator.hasNext()){

            System.out.println(" in the gridIterator");
        }

        return "success";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am correct I think this might work.. If not let me know.

```
var checks=$("#gridtable").find('input[type=checkbox]');
               var va =new Array();
              // alert(checks.length);
                for(var i=0;i<checks.length;i++)
                    {
                        if(checks[i].checked)
                            {
                             var p = checks[i].parentNode.parentNode;
                             var id=p.id;

                            va.push($("#gridtable").jqGrid('getCell',id,'cellvalue'));
                //          alert(va);
                            }
                    }
               document.getElementById("hiddenVariableID").value=va;
```

that `cellvalue`is the value that you want to send to the action class. 
I think in your case it can be any column name.

in your jsp add thi line

```
<s:hidden id="hiddenVariableID" name="selectedRows" />
```

And in your action class create `Getters` and `setters` for `selectedRows` with the type as `array`

Comment: thank you for the codes above. However, when I tried it I am getting a null value for selectedRows in my action. I provided getter/setter for selectedRows (private Integer[] selectedRows). Then I loop thru it but it is getting a null value. Here is my code:

public String runTest() throws Exception{
  
  System.out.println(" running test--");
 
  for(int i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++){
       System.out.println(selectedRows[i]);
  }
  
  return "success";
 }

Comment: Dont write your code in comments. Please provide them in code blocks .. Your code is hard to read. And did you check whether you are getting real checked values using `alert()`  or may be using `Fire bug`.. Check first whether they are null in jquery itself or not.

Comment: sorry about that confusing code. Anyway, thanks for the quick reply. I made some changes and now it is working. Instead of treating it as array, i treated it as a String and in my action, i used StringTokenizer to loop thru the values. The reason for that is because the selectedRows accumulates the values as comma delimited values, e.g., abc,def.

Comment: Thats great then .. Instead of using `StringTokenizer` you can use `string.split(",")`. Now you can accept the answer.

Comment: How to execute this code, when a delete link for deleting multiple rows on the grid is clicked?

Comment: I did not get you @Tiny ?

Comment: I want to get ids of selected/checked rows as a JavaScript array so that those ids of the selected rows can be supplied as an array as a request parameter. Those ids can then be used on the server to delete the selected rows (multiple).

Comment: Thats what my answer is please have a close look at that

Comment: This code needs to be executed, when a delete link on the grid (`navigatorDelete="true"`) is clicked. I cannot see how can this be done.

Comment: This answer if for external button links .. Not on the links of grid .. I think if you want to delete them using the links on grid generate an event when the click happens on that link.. I think `navigatorDelete="true"` when user clicks on that link `delGridRow` will be executed  I would suggest you to apply my answer under the `delGridRow` method ..

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, I used the code mentioned by "looser" (thank you very much) and I made some modifications. Instead of treating the value of selectedRows as an array, I treated it as a String that has comma delimited values, eg., abc,def. Then in my action class, I used StringTokenizer to parse the String to get the values. Here is my action method:

```
public String runTest() throws Exception{

        System.out.println(" running test--");
        StringTokenizer ids = new StringTokenizer(selectedRows, ",");
        while (ids.hasMoreTokens()) {
            int removeId = Integer.parseInt(ids.nextToken());
            System.out.println(" test id is " + removeId);
        }
        return "success";
    }
```