# How to get JSON object in Struts 2 jqGrid when using modelDriven interceptor

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp, struts2

I am creating a grid in my JSP something like below

```
   <sjg:grid gridModel="gridModel"  
          ---- other options -- >


   </sjg:grid>
```

In my `struts.xml` I am giving this action configuration

```
    <action name = "jsonAction" calss == "Action class" method = "methodName" >
      <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven" />
       <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
     <result name="success" type="json" >
        </result>
     </action>
```

In my action class

```
        public myClass extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<BeanClass>
        {
            //My list haveing getters and setters
              public gridModel getGridModel()
               {
                  return gridModel;
                 }
              public void setGridModel(List gridModel)
            { 
                  this.gridModel = gridModel;
             }

           public String methodName()
               {
                  //code here to get the list
                 }
              
            public BeanClass getModel()
                {
                 
                 return new BeanClass();
                 }

          }
```

What my doubt is I can build the grid when I don't use `ModelDriven` Interceptor. If I use it then I am unable to bind the list in jqGrid.

I did Google the issue but I can't find the proper solution. As far as I can know the issue is happening when using `modelDriven` interceptor. This interceptor will keep the action object on top of the `ValueStack`

Even I tried to use the `[1].top` but no luck.

**EDIT:**

I am implementing `ModelDriven` interface as you said I am missing  some specialization I think I have done what you said but still no luck. Don't know where I am missing.

I just did what you said do I need to change anything in my `<sjg:grid gridModel = "Here?">` ?

Still can't get the data in jqGrid.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23976899/573032

Comment: @RomanC I can understand that solution.. `The grid requires some properties to be set to function properly ` What are those properties to be set .. Can you please elaborate more..And I tried `params={
    "params.acceptParamNames", "(\\[\\d+\\]\\.)*\\w+((\\.\\w+)|(\\[\\d+\\])|(\\(\\d+\\))|(\\['\\w+'\\])|(\\('\\w+'\\)))*"` this one also.. But cant get the data .. Please help

Comment: All of them are there, also don't forget to upvote posts that you understood.

Comment: @looser http://stackoverflow.com/q/12785891/1654265

Comment: @RomanC All of them are there  . ? May be i am not in satandard to understad. Will you elobrate please .. ? i will give my reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Even I tried to use the [1].top but no luck ..

`top` references an object on the top of the stack. `[1].top` references a `top` object down the stack by index 1. In the first case it's a model pushed on the stack, in the second case it's an action bean pushed on the stack after it's created. I guess the second one contains properties necessary to provide to the grid when the action return `json` result. These properties are provided in the include parameters of json result. Your action is implemented a `ModelDriven` interface but with wrong specialization. If your action bean contains the properties that should be serialized to JSON then the model should be the action bean. You can do it if you write your action bean like

```
public MyClass extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven
{

  //My list haveing getters and setters
  public String methodName()
  {
    //code here to get the list
  }

  @Override
  public Object getModel() 
  {
    return this;
  }

}
```

Comment: I have done what you suggested but still cant able to get the data.. For more details I have edited my  question. Thanks for your time

Comment: I didn't find what you have done in the question. In either case will you follow it or not It's a working fine for me.